# Is a branch merged into trunk considered closed?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

Do I need to explicitly close a branch after merging it into trunk? Or is it implicitly considered closed after I merge it? In the former case, what should I do to close the branch? Does it mean I have to delete it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you should delete the branch after it has been reintegrated into the trunk. This is well explained in the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.reintegrate):

> Once a --reintegrate merge is done from branch to trunk, the branch is
>   no longer usable for further work. It's not able to correctly absorb
>   new trunk changes, nor can it be properly reintegrated to trunk again.
>   For this reason, if you want to keep working on your feature branch,
>   we recommend destroying it and then re-creating it from the trunk

Comment: Does destroying it mean I will lose all the history of the work done in the branch?

Comment: This is explained in the same paragraph I linked to, just the line before the one I quoted: *But wait! Isn't the history of that branch valuable? What if somebody wants to audit the evolution of your feature someday and look at all of your branch changes? No need to worry. Remember that even though your branch is no longer visible in the /branches directory, its existence is still an immutable part of the repository's history. A simple svn log command on the /branches URL will show the entire history of your branch.*

Comment: Oh, but i'm worry! Because after destroying the branch I cannot make change diffs of the source code files parted in the deleted branch ....